# Why is my list returning to its old state after being modified in a function?

Tags: python

```
def optimizeDeliveryOrder(self, depot, deliveries):
        # Initialize current solution as a random solution.
        currentSolution = deliveries.copy()
        random.shuffle(currentSolution)

        # Keep track of the best solution so far.
        bestSolution = currentSolution.copy()
        bestDistance = deliveryRouteCrowDistance(depot, currentSolution)

        oldCrowDistance = deliveryRouteCrowDistance(depot, deliveries)

        deliveries = bestSolution.copy()

        return oldCrowDistance, bestDistance

class DeliveryOptimizerTest(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_optimizeDeliverOrder(self):
            deliveries = [
                DeliveryRequest('', GeoCoord('2','3') ),
                DeliveryRequest('', GeoCoord('42','42') ),
                DeliveryRequest('', GeoCoord('0','0') )
            ]
            depot = GeoCoord('30', '5')
            oldCrowDistance, newCrowDistance = optimizer1.optimizeDeliveryOrder(depot, deliveries)
```

So I have been debugging this thing for a while and when I call oldCrowDistance, newCrowDistance = optimizer1.optimizeDeliveryOrder(depot, deliveries) in my unit test, my deliveries list is correctly modified within the function (deliveries = bestSolution.copy()).
However, as soon as it leaves the function, the deliveries list reverts back to its old state.
Lists are mutable and so are classes. Some help or even hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me simplify your code for you:

```
def foo(deliveries):
    deliveries = [2]

deliveries = [1]
foo(deliveries)
assert deliveries == [1]
```

You correctly identify that lists are mutable, but name assignment is not a way of mutating an object.  The code above simply rebinds the list `[2]` to the variable `deliveries`, which has no effect outside the scope of function `foo`.

```
def foo(deliveries):
    deliveries[:] = [2]

deliveries = [1]
foo(deliveries)
assert deliveries == [2]
```

The above code uses `[:]` to replace the *contents* of deliveries.  There are other ways to modify contents of a list (e.g. remove, delete), but slice assignment is fairly concise.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so much. I guessed that was what was happening so I kept playing around with list = anotherList.copy() vs list = anotherList but I didn't know the [:] syntax.

Comment: I made that simple change and it is correctly working. Thank you so much! I will upvote and accept solution as soon as I can (it says I have to wait 5 mins).

Comment: Glad I could help.  It can be hard to dig out those errors when there are a lot of other moving parts